# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required identifier property not found for class com.domain.Profile! - Mongo, SpringBoot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am using SpringBoot with Mongo in my project.

I have a `Profile` model that looks like this.

```
@Data
@Document
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Profile {
    private String birthDate;
    private Stirng city;
    private String country;  
}
```

I can add it to Mongo via postman but when I try to `delete` it from Mongo by `Id` I am getting following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required identifier property not found for class com.domain.Profile!
```

This is deleteById method.

```
 @DeleteMapping(value = "/{profileId}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteById(@PathVariable String profileId) {
        if (profileRepository.existsById(profileId)) {
            profileRepository.deleteById(profileId);
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Profile properly deleted.",HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Profile not found.", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
```

I use `Postman` like this:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

[image]

where 23 is profileId